# Can NLog write to RavenDB database

Tags: .net, ravendb, nlog

Want to try nosql and need to improve logging (write to some DB instead of files..). For now i use SQLCE for that. Can i use NLog and write to RavenDB for example? If 'yes' please provide some sample NLog configuratoin file. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but you would have to write the appender that does this yourself, I don't think there is an OOTB appender for this.